# How do I install Exchange System Manager without the original install media?

Tags: windows-xp, exchange-2003

Is there a public download or other workaround for this? I'm trying to install the Exchange 2003 ESM on to an XPSP3 desktop.

Comment: Ask someone with a technet subscription to download the media for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17836
(Even if it says vista, it probably works on XP, too)